# How to edit modal input area vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am developing task manager app and ı have a problem.
I want to edit existing task but when i use v-model my task editing withoute save button. I dont want this.
I want to edit with save button and make api call after click save buttton to save database.

How can i do this?
Can i use assigne props to new variable or do you have any idea?

```
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{task.name}}</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="taskNameInput">Task Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Please enter new task name"
                class="form-control"
                id="taskNameInput"
                maxlength="25"
                v-model="task.name"
              />



      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            style="width: 100%"
            class="btn btn-success"
          >
            Save Task
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            style="width: 100%"
            class="btn btn-success"
          >
            Delete Task
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "UpdateModal",
    props: ["task"],

    methods: {
        updateTask(){
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273242/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-for-create-edit-functions-in-vue-js

Comment: How about not using `v-model` and just getting the value directly from input on save?

Answer (score 0):

**You need @click  in button tags and the function async in methods to call your API.**

**look here about event handling:** 
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#listening-to-events

**and look here about async calls using axios:** 
https://serversideup.net/using-axios-to-make-api-requests-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is, that you have one `createTask` (or similar) and one `updateTask` method. You now want to call one of these functions based on the passed property `task`.

So your button must react based on the mode (Edit/Save) to execute the right method. Otherwise, if you find it easier, you can use a wrapper method and make the decision there.

```html
 <button
            type="button"
            style="width: 100%"
            class="btn btn-success"
            @click="mode == 'Edit' ? updateTask() : createTask()" // click-function based on the mode
          >
 {{mode}} Task
</button>
```

And add in your scipt the following:

```js
data: {
    mode: 'Save' // default mode should be save
},
mounted() {         
    if(this.task.name) // identify if task already exist
        this.mode = "Edit";         
},
```